# grammatical confusion

Tags: grammar

When subject "I" is implicit, which one is correct?

> a) not going to give up until I reach the end
>
> b) is not going to give up until I reach the end
>
> c) am not going to give up until I reach the end

Comment: Do you mean "Which of these can act, as it stands, as a subordinate clause with the implicit subject *I*?"

Comment: If the subject I is implicit, by definition, the verb must be: am or do.

Answer (score 2):

a) and c) are both correct.
b) is definitely wrong.

Conversationally you might encounter (a) as a response to a question.
Q: When are you going to give up?
A: Not going to give up until I reach the end.

(c) is a style sometimes found in diaries, personal notes and very informal correspondence:
Am feeling determined.  Want to finish this.  Am not going to give up until I reach the end.